# Combining classifiers' output based on F1-scores

Tags: machine-learning, classification, named-entity-recognition

I have 4 classifiers available (already trained), for a 4-class classification problem. For a given dataset, I have the output of each of the classifiers, as well as their Recall, Precision and F1-scores for each of the classes.

What would be the best algorithm (or available existing algorithms) to combine the predictions of these classifiers to get 1 single final prediction, taking into consideration that some of the classifiers have higher f1-scores than others for specific classes?

**EDIT**

My main problem is that some classifiers have better F1 for specific classes.

So let's say Classifier1 (C1) predicted class A, and  has a f1 of 0.90 for class A. Then  Classifier2 (C2) predicted class B, and has a f1 of 0.80 for class B.

My first thought would be to choose C1 prediction based on its higher f1, but what if for example we also know that C2 has a f1 score of 0.999 for class A? If C2 is that good at predicting class A (even better than C1) but did not predict it, that should increase the probability that the real class is not A, I believe.

On the other and, if C2 had a really low f1 for class A that should make it even more likely that the real class was A, not only because C1 predicted A and it's good at it, but also because C2 is not good in predicting that class explaining why it might have failed to detect it

I'm not sure how to deal with these questions in practice though.

Comment: Need more details. Do the 4 classifiers work on one vs all approach, ie they are only used to predict if the sample belongs to a specific class or not. Or they are all individually predicting from all 4 classes? Some sample code and data input output will be preferred.

Comment: All the classifiers predicted all classes individually (we're talking about different named entity recognition toolkits, so I can't provide code). Right now I'm only working with the output of each of these toolkits and I want some voting system to see if I can improve the performance by combining their outputs in some way. I already came up with a few ideas that worked, I was just looking for some maybe existent state of the art method to do this

Comment: @VivekKumar I've added an example of a specific situation to try to explain better what I'm looking for

Comment: So in short, you want a combination of classifier where the output is of the classifier which has highest f1 for that class.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make waited votes, where the vote from the classifier with highest f1-score have the highest weight. Then you simply chose the class with the highest amount score.

Comment: Problem is that each classifier has a different F1 for each class. I edited my question with a more specific example of my problem